# Ajax request to load .php file not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to load contents from postcode.php file into a `#postcodeList` div, but it is not working (nothing happens). I checked postcode.php file it echoes al correct information.

```
var loadicecream = document.getElementById("iceCreams");
loadicecream.addEventListener("click", iceAjax, false);

function iceAjax() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","ice-cream-list.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    document.getElementById("ice-cream-list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Can you not just use jQuery?

Comment: If all they need is to load a piece of data on a div, it doesn't really seem logical to add a huge framework onto the page for the user to load when it can be done with a couple of lines of native JS code.

Comment: @Adosi sure I could and I plan to, but I want to understand in Standard javascript first

Comment: Why are you using the ActiveX fallback for XHR? No browser that needs it will support `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Quentin Was part of example in w3c, but I see your point, there is no sense in it in this particular situation.

Comment: @Ilja — I doubt the W3C would provide such an example, are you confusing them with the awful w3schools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the query to execute asynchronously (the third parameter to open function) and then you synchronously try to read the value. This happens before the query has been sent, so it will always be empty.

Either run the load synchronously, or set the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange to point into a function where you handle the loaded state. The best way is to do it asynchronously since you don't want to block the user from using the page while loading data.

Quick example, only handles the success case:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("postcodeList").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","postcode.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Read up on the documentation for the onreadystatechange, at least you want to handle the case where there is a timeout or some error, otherwise the user won't know something went wrong.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit, still new to ajax, Where would I set it to .onreadystatechange, and should 3rd parameter be set to false?

Comment: If you set the third parameter to false, the `send()` doesn't return until it has loaded the data (or failed to load it). This causes the browser to wait, which is not nice. I added a simple success case code, which runs asynchronously. You can add the error handling to make it better.

Comment: Still, nothing happens. Does it play a role that php file contains a SELECT query from database and echoes info? opened on its own it displays all correct information though. And can href="#" be causing this?

Comment: No, the internals have nothing to do with it. The request doesn't care about those. You can add debugging info into the onreadystatechange function to see what is going on (alert or console.log)

Comment: Yea gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null, not sure what it is, addEventListener looks correct to me

Comment: And the code is after the actual div? If it's run before, it can't find that element and it will be null, giving that error.

Comment: got it working, was another addEventListener on a page that was causing an error.